# How to Properly Redirect in AspNetCore 3.0 Action Filter Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to redirect to another action for setup if the account setup is not complete. 
However, when I use this action filter:

```
public sealed class AccountSetupFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        ...
        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
               await UserRequiresServiceAccount(context.HttpContext.User))
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Setup", "Home", null);
            }
            else
            {
                await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
            }
        }
...
}
```

I get an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is 
of type 'Models.SetupModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model 
item of type 'Models.OriginalControllerModel'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object value)
```

This is not expected because the new view requires a SetupModel. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you see the 302 triggered by the `RedirectToAction` and then the next request to the new location fails? Or rather, it's the filter code that fails immediately, without even returning the 302?

Comment: I could see a 302 and then the error. And I figured it out. Turns out I had a partial view that wanted a model so that it could use the form tag helpers. I just passed an empty object into it and it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a partial view referenced from the layout page that wanted a model so that it could make a login form. The page would load fine when no model was present as it only used the model for the tag helpers, but it would not work when an actual model was used. The solution was to just add a `model="new MyEmptyModel()"` to the partial tag helper.